# List of Dictionaries from a csv file

Tags: python, file-handling

Using File handling concept of python, I created a list of dictionary from .csv file. Now I am suppose to remove newline character  from that list which is present between any two dictionaries.
I can't use strip with element of list coz it is a dictionary not STRING. So what choice do I have?

Comment: First and best choice: present your code here so that we might help - otherwise your question will likely be closed soon.

Comment: I didn't understand how a newline character is being present between two dictionaries. Aren't they already dictionaries? We need example data and code.

Comment: You should do it when you are creating the list of dictionaries as opposed to removing them after-the-fact. Please add your code that creates the list.

Answer (score 3):

```
for dic in list_of_dictionaries:
    for key, value in dic.items():
        if isinstance(value, str):
            dic[key]=value.strip()
```

P.S. For python2 you will have to use `isinstance(value, basestring)` instead